# How to add highlighting to exposed views_autocomplete_filter in Drupal 8

Tags: views, 8, theming

Is there a way (a hook perhaps) that would allow me to modify the autocomplete fields returned by an exposed views_autocomplete_filter field?  I'd like to style the text typed into the field differently from the rest of the suggestion text.

Something like this:

------------------
| term_          |
------------------------------
| term**inal emulators**      | 
------------------------------
| **de**term**ination**         |
------------------------------
| **mid**term **exams**      |
------------------------------

Comment: Could be done via javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 2):

So it seems it is necessary to extend the `ViewsAutocompleteFiltersController` class to do this.  In order to override the routing so that a custom controller can be used instead, an entry must be added to `/mymodule/mymodule.services.yml`:

```
services:
  mymodule.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\Routing\RouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Then provide your `/mymodule/src/Routing/RouteSubscriber.php` file, which redirects to our local `ViewsAutocompleteFiltersController`

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Listens to the dynamic route events.
 */
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    // Replace "some.route.name" below with the actual route you want to override.
    if ($route = $collection->get('viewsfilters.autocomplete')) {
      $route->setDefaults(array(
        '_controller' => '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\ViewsAutocompleteFiltersController::autocomplete',
      ));
    }
  }
}
```

Finally provide your local `/mymodule/src/Controller/ViewsAutocompleteFiltersController.php` which filters for the view of interest, then modifies the output of the base `ViewsAutocompleteFiltersController`.  The tricky part of that process is that the `data` member of the `JsonResponse` output is protected, so we use a customized `JsonResponse` wrapper to perform the highlighting:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

/**
 * Overrides default ViewsAutocompleteFiltersController to provide highlighting of autocomplete suggestions
 */
class ViewsAutocompleteFiltersController extends \Drupal\views_autocomplete_filters\Controller\ViewsAutocompleteFiltersController {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc]
   */
  public function autocomplete(Request $request, $view_name, $view_display, $filter_name, $view_args) {

    $response = parent::autocomplete($request, $view_name, $view_display, $filter_name, $view_args);
    if($response instanceof JsonResponse && $view_name === 'my_view' && $view_display === 'my_view_display') {
      $response = new HighlightedJsonResponse($response, $request->query->get('q'));
    }
    return $response;
  }

}


/**
 * Overrides default JsonResponse to provide highlighting of autocomplete suggestions
 */
class HighlightedJsonResponse extends JsonResponse {

  function __construct($jsonResponse, $q) {

    $data = \json_decode($jsonResponse->data);
    if(isset($q)) {
      $qPattern = '/(' . preg_quote($q, '/') . ')/i';
      foreach($data as &$datum) {
        if(isset($datum->label)) {
          $datum->label = '<b>' . \preg_replace($qPattern, '</b>$0<b>', $datum->label) . '</b>';
          $datum->label = \str_replace("<b></b>","",$datum->label);
        }
      }
    }

    parent::__construct($data, $jsonResponse->statusCode, $jsonResponse->headers->all());

  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @mike, Your code works for my requirement, Thank you so much, but, in label, while appending <span> tag, it appends to href which is inside label. So, when I select a result from autocomplete suggestions, it taking to a url like this: https://www.drupal.org/community/contributor-guide/use-or-<span>improve</span>-your-skills